# Get a range date and search a string

Tags: date, vbscript, date-range

I have 2 date input fields, **Start** and **End**, and I have a String whom I would like to search for a range of dates, the range between **Start** and **End**.

For example:

```
Start: 20/02/2014
End: 25/02/2014
MyText: "In 21/02/2014 something happened"
```

What I am trying to do is get the dates between **Start** and **End**, in this case:

```
20/02/2014
21/02/2014
22/02/2014
23/02/2014
24/02/2014
25/02/2014
```

And search in the **MyText**, if one of the dates are inside it. If yes, I will `Response.Write` something.

At first I dunno how to get the array(?) of dates based on the **Start** and **End** input fields. And, I can search a string using **InStr**, but how to search for the array(?)

I just have a single date search, like:

```
<%
   IF InStr(MyText, Now()) >= 1 THEN
%>
   Found!
<%
   ELSE
%>
   Not Found!
<%
   END IF
%>
```

Comment: Where does MyText come from and how does it look (sample)?

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner, Its a string I get it from the database, and it is like MyText: "In 21/02/2014 something happened", and could have more text. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strStartDate will be your start date

strEndDate will be your end date

First thing we do is set the default value for whether or not we found your string. Next we find the difference between your start and end date in days, we then loop through every day between the start and end date. We use the DateAdd function to determine how far into the loop we are from the start, then we search the MyText string for the date found with the DateAdd function. If we find it, we set the boolDateFound variable to True and exit the loop.

```
<%
boolDateFound = False
For intDateDiff = 0 to DateDiff("d",strStartDate,strEndDate)

  arrDateParts = Split(DateAdd("d",intDateDiff,strStartDate),"/")
  If arrDateParts(1) <= 9 Then
    arrDateParts(1) = "0" & arrDateParts(1)
  End If
  strCheckDate = arrDateParts(0) & "/" & arrDateParts(1) & "/" & arrDateParts(2)

  Response.Write "Date: " & strCheckDate

  If InStr(MyText, strCheckDate) > 0 Then
    boolDateFound = True
    Exit For
  End If
Next

If boolDateFound Then%>
Found!
<%Else%>
Not Found
<%End If%>
```

Comment: Thanks. I am trying but the code is returning Not Found for all. The dates and the MyText are strings, could be this?

Comment: Nope it should work fine. You can echo each line and make sure the dates are formatted the same. I'll update the code.

Comment: This helps, what is happening is I have formatted all my dates to this: DD/MM/YYYY and the check is looking for the standard DD/M/YYYY. The code I am using is: `StartDate= Right("0" & CStr(Day(CDate(StartDate))), 2) & "/" & Right("0" & CStr(Month(CDate(StartDate))), 2) & "/" & CStr(Year(CDate(StartDate)))`. Can we use it in your code above? Thanks again

Comment: Check whether `DateAdd("d",intDateDiff,strStartDate)` (stringyfied/CStr()) looks like your dates. Depending on the defaults/local settings is lottery.

Comment: `DateAdd("d",intDateDiff,strStartDate)` brings DD/M/YYYY. Can it look for DD/MM/YYYY?

Comment: Nathan, I started another question, based on your code, if you have some spare time, will help a lot (again): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22014055/loop-throught-a-description-find-if-and-count Thanks dude.

Answer (score 2):

Use a RegExp to find dd/mm/yyyy dates in your Text, generate a Date (DateSerial) from the parts of each string, compare the found date against the range, store if appropriate.

In Code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim greDate : Set greDate = New RegExp
greDate.Global  = True
greDate.Pattern = "(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})"  ' dd/mm/yyyy

Dim aTests : aTests = Array( _
      "In 21/02/2014 something happened" _
    , "" _
    , "pi 19/02/2014 pa 26/02/2014 po" _
    , "In 21/02/2013 something happened" _
    , "pi 19/02/2014 pu 20/02/2014 pa 21/02/2014 22/02/2014  23/02/2014  24/02/2014  25/02/2014 26/02/2014 po" _
)
Dim sTest
Dim dtFrom : dtFrom = #2/20/2014#
Dim dtTo   : dtTo   = #2/25/2014#
For Each sTest In aTests
    WScript.Echo "-----", qq(sTest)
    Dim aDates : aDates = getDatesFrom(sTest, dtFrom, dtTo)
    If -1 = UBound(aDates) Then
      WScript.Echo " no interesting dates found."
    Else
      WScript.Echo " found (m/d/yyyy!)", Join(aDates, ", ")
    End If
Next

Function getDatesFrom(sText, dtFrom, dtTo)
  ReDim aTmp(-1)
  Dim oMTS : Set oMTS = greDate.Execute(sText)
  Dim oMT, dtFound
  For Each oMT In oMTS
      ' dd/mm/yyyy
      dtFound = DateSerial(CInt(oMT.SubMatches(2)), cInt(oMT.SubMatches(1)), CInt(oMT.SubMatches(0)))
      If dtFound >= dtFrom And dtFound <= dtTo Then
        ReDim Preserve aTmp(Ubound(aTmp) + 1)
        aTmp(Ubound(aTmp)) = dtFound
      End If
  Next
  getDatesFrom = aTmp
End Function

Function qq(s) : qq = """" & s & """" : End Function
```

output:

```
cscript 21994835.vbs
----- "In 21/02/2014 something happened"
 found (m/d/yyyy!) 2/21/2014
----- ""
 no interesting dates found.
----- "pi 19/02/2014 pa 26/02/2014 po"
 no interesting dates found.
----- "In 21/02/2013 something happened"
 no interesting dates found.
----- "pi 19/02/2014 pu 20/02/2014 pa 21/02/2014 22/02/2014  23/02/2014  24/02/2014  25/02/2014 26/02/2014 po"
 found (m/d/yyyy!) 2/20/2014, 2/21/2014, 2/22/2014, 2/23/2014, 2/24/2014, 2/25/2014
```

Comment: @Ekkeghard. Thanks for the code, I see how much of work you put on it. I just went for the Nathan because it was smaller and objective. Thanks a lot.

Comment: +1. @Khrys sometimes you may have to write much code and it's certainly not a bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, you like small code:

```
sd = cDate("20/02/2014")
ed = cDate("25/02/2014")
testString = "In 21/02/2014 something happened"

do
    found = (instr(testString, CreateObject("System.Text.Stringbuilder").AppendFormat("{0:dd}/{0:MM}/{0:yyyy}", sd).ToString()) > 0)
    sd = cDate(sd + 1)
loop until sd > ed or found

if found then wscript.echo "I found the date!"
```

(please note that `sd` is always one day ahead of the found date, you need an additional `If found then exit do` to circumvent that).

EDIT: After discussion in the comments, I think this is the better approach: Extract the date from the text and see if it is larger or equal than the startdate and smaller or equal than the end date:

```
sd = cDate("20/02/2014")
ed = cDate("25/02/2014")
testString = "In 21/02/2014 something happened"

set re = new regexp
re.pattern = "\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}"

for each match in re.execute(testString)
    if cDate(match) >= sd and cDate(match) <= ed then wscript.echo "Found date " & match
next
```

Comment: using date literals would be shorter (and less risky).

Comment: @Ekkehard.Horner I agree, but only if you are in the lucky position to have date literals. Most of the time they are provided as string variables. Honestly, I would solve it by extracting the date with a RegExp like you did, convert it to a date and see if it equals or is more than startdate and equals or is less than enddate. More code, much easier and faster.

Comment: That just leaves the risks of CDate(). The *only* reliable way from a string to a date is DateSerial() fed with the parts in the correct order.