# Loop throught a description, find a string and count

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have a table with, for this example, 2 columns:

```
Person
Description
```

I need to create a result table like this:

```
Person     Yes     No     Total
John       1       5      6
Laura      4       9      13
Peter      0       1      1
Total      5       15     20
```

The person I get it straight, but for the description I have to do a check if there is a date inside the string, Nathan Rice helped me here about it: [Get a range date and search a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21994835/get-a-range-date-and-search-a-string). One Person can have N descriptions, so I need to loop it. If the date was found in description add 1 to Yes, else add 1 to No.

**CODE UPDATED**

```
<%
varYesTotal = 0
varNoTotal = 0
Do While Not rsPerson.EOF
    varYes = 0
    varNo = 0
    strPersonName = rsPerson("Person")

    Set rsCheckYesNo = T.Execute("SELECT Description FROM Person Where Person= '" & strPersonName & "' ORDER BY Person ASC")
    strDescription= rsCheckYesNo("Description")

    For intDateDiff = 0 to DateDiff("d",DataInicial,DataFinal)
        arrDateParts = Split(DateAdd("d",intDateDiff,DataInicial),"/")
        If arrDateParts(1) <= 9 Then
            arrDateParts(1) = "0" & arrDateParts(1)
        End If

        strCheckDate = arrDateParts(0) & "/" & arrDateParts(1) & "/" & arrDateParts(2)

        Do While Not rsCheckYesNo.EOF
            strDescription= rsCheckYesNo("Description")

            boolDateFound = False

            If InStr(strDescription, strCheckDate) > 0 Then
                boolDateFound = True
                varYes = varYes + 1
            Else
                varNo = varNo + 1
            End If

        rsCheckYesNo.MoveNext
        Loop                                
    Next
%>
```

Comment: Are you trying to reinsert this data into the database or just display it in a table?

Comment: @Nathan, Just display in a table : )

Comment: I posted the fixes for your code. One suggestion would be to type your variables by prefixing them. It makes the code more readable because you know what kind of variables are being passed around and how they should be accessed. I went ahead and did that throughout your code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%
Set rsPerson= T.Execute("SELECT DISTINCT Person FROM Table")
If Not rsPerson.EOF Then
%>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Person</th>
            <th>Yes</th>
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <%
    'We need 2 sets of counters, one set that gets set
    'to zero so we can total all the records.
    varYesTotal = 0
    varNoTotal = 0
    Do While Not rsPerson.EOF
        'The other set of counters gets reset per user
        'so it should be inside the users loop.
        varYes = 0
        varNo = 0
        strPersonName = rsPerson("Person")

        Set rsCheckYesNo = T.Execute("SELECT Description FROM Person Where Person= '" & strPersonName & "' ORDER BY Person ASC")
        strDescription= rsCheckYesNo("Description")

        Do While Not rsCheckYesNo.EOF
            'Start Nathan Rice Code
            boolDateFound = False
            For intDateDiff = 0 to DateDiff("d",DataInicial,DataFinal)
                arrDateParts = Split(DateAdd("d",intDateDiff,DataInicial),"/")
                If arrDateParts(1) <= 9 Then
                    arrDateParts(1) = "0" & arrDateParts(1)
                End If
                strCheckDate = arrDateParts(0) & "/" & arrDateParts(1) & "/" & arrDateParts(2)

                If InStr(strDescription, strCheckDate) > 0 Then
                    boolDateFound = True
                    varYes = varYes + 1
                    Exit For
                Else
                    varNo = varNo + 1
                End If
            Next
            'End Nathan Rice Code

            rsCheckYesNo.MoveNext
        Loop
    %>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><%=strPersonName%></td>
            <td><%=varYes%></td>
            <td><%=varNo%></td>
            <td><%=(varYes + varNo)%></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <%
        varYesTotal = varYesTotal + varYes
        varNoTotal = varNoTotal + varNo
        rsPerson.MoveNext
    Loop
    rsPerson.Close
    %>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td>Total</td>
            <td><%=varYesTotal%></td>
            <td><%=varNoTotal%></td>
            <td><%=(varYesTotal+varNoTotal)%></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
<%
End If
%>
```

Comment: Hi Nathan, thanks. Just tested the code, but I am missing something. The result looks is return min 0 and max 3 for varYes and varNo, I think it is handling the data range. I think the The strDescription in the rsCheckYesNo needs a loop, the query returns 0 or N lines for strDescription. I tried but the code is getting time out. What do you think? Thanks again for your time.

Comment: I fixed it. I had missed 2 variable name changes.

Comment: Thanks Nathan. I was debugging and I found the results are coming x3 I think it was because the dates from start to finish. So I move the `Do While Not rsCheckYesNo.EOF` to above the `If InStr(strDescription, strCheckDate) > 0 Then` line. And now the results are right, but the validation for varYes and varNo is weird. I think if it finds the first occurrence for varYes, it is exiting the block... I am not sure... still debugging. Thanks for any more info, again.

Comment: Ok The way the code is now it looking for only the first date. Should be looking for the range without triple the varYes or varNo. I did not made big changes... should I post the code I have now? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Your plan should look like this:

```
PreP for whole task
  Database
  Date range
  Total
  Print header
Get persons
For all persons
    PreP for person
    Get name
    Get descriptions
    For all descriptions
        Check and count
    Next 
    PostP for person
      Compute yes/no/all (one from two)
      Print row
      Update total
Next
PostP for whole task
  Print total
  Database
```

Looks like your code lacks the description loop.

**Update:**

In code:

```
Option Explicit

Dim greDate : Set greDate = New RegExp
greDate.Global  = True
greDate.Pattern = "(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})"  ' dd/mm/yyyy

Dim aTotal : aTotal = Array(0,0,0)

Dim aTests : aTests = Array( _
      Array(    "peter" _
              , "In 21/02/2014 something happened") _
    , Array(    "paul" _
              , "pi 19/02/2014 pa 26/02/2014 po" _
              , "In 21/02/2013 something happened") _
    , Array(    "mary" _
              , "pi 19/02/2014 pu 20/02/2014 25/02/2014 26/02/2014 po" _
              , "pi 19/02/2014 pu 20/02/2014 ") _
)
Dim aPers
Dim dtFrom : dtFrom = #2/20/2014#
Dim dtTo   : dtTo   = #2/25/2014#
For Each aPers In aTests
    WScript.Echo "#####", aPers(0)
    Dim aPSum : aPSum = Array(0, 0, 0)
    Dim nDescr
    For nDescr = 1 To UBound(aPers)
        Dim sTest : sTest = aPers(nDescr)
        WScript.Echo "-----", qq(sTest)
        Dim aDates : aDates = getDatesFrom(sTest, dtFrom, dtTo)
        If -1 = UBound(aDates) Then
           WScript.Echo " no interesting dates found."
           aPSum(1) = aPSum(1) + 1
        Else
           WScript.Echo " found (m/d/yyyy!)", Join(aDates, ", ")
           aPSum(0) = aPSum(0) + 1
        End If
    Next
    aPSum(2) = aPSum(0) + aPSum(1)
    WScript.Echo "*****", Join(aPSum)
    Dim i
    For i = 0 To UBound(aTotal) : aTotal(i) = aTotal(i) + aPSum(i) : Next
Next
WScript.Echo "#####", Join(aTotal)

Function getDatesFrom(sText, dtFrom, dtTo)
  ReDim aTmp(-1)
  Dim oMTS : Set oMTS = greDate.Execute(sText)
  Dim oMT, dtFound
  For Each oMT In oMTS
      ' dd/mm/yyyy
      dtFound = DateSerial(CInt(oMT.SubMatches(2)), cInt(oMT.SubMatches(1)), CInt(oMT.SubMatches(0)))
      If dtFound >= dtFrom And dtFound <= dtTo Then
        ReDim Preserve aTmp(Ubound(aTmp) + 1)
        aTmp(Ubound(aTmp)) = dtFound
      End If
  Next
  getDatesFrom = aTmp
End Function

Function qq(s) : qq = """" & s & """" : End Function
```

output:

```
cscript 21994835-2.vbs
##### peter
----- "In 21/02/2014 something happened"
 found (m/d/yyyy!) 2/21/2014
***** 1 0 1
##### paul
----- "pi 19/02/2014 pa 26/02/2014 po"
 no interesting dates found.
----- "In 21/02/2013 something happened"
 no interesting dates found.
***** 0 2 2
##### mary
----- "pi 19/02/2014 pu 20/02/2014 25/02/2014 26/02/2014 po"
 found (m/d/yyyy!) 2/20/2014, 2/25/2014
----- "pi 19/02/2014 pu 20/02/2014 "
 found (m/d/yyyy!) 2/20/2014
***** 2 0 2
##### 3 2 5
```

Comment: yeah I have that feeling too ><

Comment: Thanks Ekkehard, I still find a little bit difficult to understand the code, because I am using Classic ASP like to code I showed... gonna check your code line by line and try to adapt to my case... yo dude, thanks a lot...